# Can't find an element in the Web Inspector

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web-inspector

There's an *element* that appears on the site, but I *can't seem to find it in the inspector of the browser*. I would like to hide it somehow.

On this page: http://gdhbau.hu/#bemutatkozas

It is the "**BEZÁR**" word with white color, next to the "Becsuk" button, when clicking on the "MÉG TÖBB" button (to expand the content).
This problem shows up when I turn on the "Automatically add paragraphs" in the WordPress SiteOirgin editor; but I need to use it, otherwise the content falls apart.

EDIT: This is with the plug-in called: "Collapse-O-Matic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never find it since it's not an element.

It's part of the image in the background http://gdhbau.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/bemu-bg-large.jpg